# Building an ORM - mysqli vs regular SQL vs PDO

Tags: php, orm, pdo, mysqli

I have been looking for a very light weight PHP ORM library and I ran across a few good choices. Unfortunately, most choices require some form of
configuration, e.g. adding more fields to the class and many of them
are not so intuitive.

I do not want to use a framework, but prefer just the ORM for Q&D
prototypes.

Anyway, I started building my own PHP ORM library called SORM (Simple ORM). It is very much in  alpha state. You can checkout the code and examples at

https://github.com/teraom/sorm

I would appreciate if you can provide some feedback or directions on
how to proceed, things to change etc.
I am interested in using mysqli for database queries, specifically for prepared
statements, so as to avoid SQL injection.

1. Is there a way to use prepared statements with regular PHP - SQL
   functions? Or prevent SQL injection by other means?
   https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php
2. Is mysqli installed by default when you install PHP? (PHP 5.2 and
   above)
3. I know very little about PDO. Is PDO installed by default in PHP 5.2 and above? Does PDO come into picture too?

Thanks,
Bharad

Comment: I have a quick suggestion for you: indent your code. Also, try  to break lines that are more than 80 characters long. Comments should never be more than 80 characters a line.

Comment: If you want to build something for the future, use PDO.

Comment: @Rafe - Thanks for the feedback. I added indentation and broke down large lines in the readme file.

Comment: @Bharadwaj also, you'll need a license. Try Apaches, BSD, MIT, or LGPL.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler, I agree that lines of code should be kept short, but 80 chars per line is so obselete... Whitespaces for indentation can easily be 20 or more characters (`if` statement in a loop that is inside of a class method - not too many levels are needed for growing indent to 20 characters), names of variable also can be more than 20 characters long (e.g., `$canTaskGroupBeCancelled`), same goes for method names. 80 char limit comes from historical times when screens were smaller and letters on screen were bigger. Nowadays, many screens can display more than 240 normal-sized letters.

Comment: @Rafe - I have decided to go with MIT license. I know it is customary to add a license.txt file. I ll include the license text inline

Comment: @Rafe Kettler, I have seen some java code that is broken to meet that "max 80 chars" limit - with names of variables longer than few symbols (e.g., `numberOfPersons` instead of `num`) it looks terrible and unmaintainable.

Comment: @binaryLV vim and emacs are extremely popular, both of which by default only display 80 characters per line. IMO lines should rarely be over 80 lines and never over 100. My screen can show 240 characters, but I like to be able to have 3 windows side-by-side. Java might be the exception because it's too damn verbose.

Comment: @binaryLV - I use a 13" macbook which has a small screen to start with and I use vim and textmate. i think it is better to keep it under 80, AS FAR AS POSSIBLE.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler, object oriented PHP code with self-describing var/func/const names also is verbose. It really depends on programmer / company. About having windows side-by-side - others solve lack of horizontal space by adding secondary monitor (this is really handy). Lack of vertical space cannot be solved that easily. P.S. I agree that lines of code should be kept as short as possible to improve readibility, I just don't agree with "max 80 chars per line in all situations". It really depends, sometimes it should be 80, sometimes 120, sometimes - 160 (with most rows still being below 80).

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to use prepared statements with regular PHP - SQL functions?

Only when supported by the regular functions.  The decrepit "mysql" extension does not provide this functionality.  Some others do, like the one for PostgreSQL.

> Is mysqli installed by default when you install PHP? (PHP 5.2 and above)

This is not answerable, as it depends on how PHP was compiled (if it's a custom installation), or whether it was installed via a package manager.  If it was installed through a package manager, then it's very likely that all database support might be in an *optional* add-on package.  However, if mysql support *in general* is enabled, the "mysqli" extension should be available.

> Is PDO installed by default in PHP 5.2 and above?

Same answer as before -- it depends on how PHP was installed.  It's *enabled* by default when compiling, but it might not be available depending on package management.

In general, you can rely on PDO being available *most* of the time.  When it's not, it's either going to be oversight on behalf of the sysadmin, or an intentional decision to disable it by an idiot manager.

A *lot* of modern PHP is built assuming PDO will be there.  There's not *too* much harm in making adapters for both PDO and mysqli, as both have *generally* similar feature sets.  Just watch out for the weird, weird way that [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) works -- it expects *one* call with all of the things to bind, *by reference*.  This tends to turn people off.

---

Another option: Instead of building on top of PDO directly, build on top of another wrapper.  I don't want to get all Inception on you, but take a peek at [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html).  Yes, I know you don't want to use a framework, but take a look at it anyway.  It has adapters for the various PDO flavors, mysqli, Oracle, and DB2.  It's also quite comprehensive, and the query builder (Zend_Db_Select) is pretty handy.

There are lots of other options in this area, like [good old PEAR MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/redirected), which uses [emulation to fake prepared statements](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-execute.php) and placeholders.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response, appreciate it. I have used ZEND in the past and it was bloated for my projects. I am currently using DOOPHP, a lovely and light weight framework!  In fact, I have modeled my ORM mostly after DOOPHP.